# How to fix "WebSocket connection failed' in channels official tutorial

Tags: django, channel

I am following channels chat app tutorial. I have done everything on the tutorial but I seem to not be getting messages to show in the text area.

```
var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://' + window.location.host +
    '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var message = data['message'];
    document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
};

chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {

    console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
};
```

Comment: where are you getting this error? what do you see in your back-end console? is there an error stack trace?

Comment: I was seeing an error message on chrome console that my socket connection faild. And line 2 of above code was underlined in red.

Comment: Also line '''chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
''' was underlined in red

Comment: What’s `roomName` in your browser source?

Comment: I mean look at your javascript code in your browser developer tools (either the page source if it's embedded in your HTML page or the source of the JS file if it's served separately). And tell us what the line `var roomName = {{ room_name_json }}` looks like in your browser. Or add a line `console.log(roomName)` to print it to console in your browser.

Comment: the room name is the name of the room i entered( as expected in the tutorial). I typed lobby and room name is "lobby".

Comment: you're sure it's the string "lobby" when you look at the javascript in your browser developer tools? i.e. you see `var roomName = "lobby";` when you look at the source inside Chrome/Edge/Firefox/Safari?

Comment: sorry, you didn't link to the tutorial, so that wasn't entirely clear to me. Did you follow the step where you check using a django shell that your channel layer can establish a connection and communicate with your redis server?

Comment: yes. that is what I saw. and the error message I saw previously is not there again bt yet message still not showing in txt area.

Comment: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html this is the tutorial. I did not see that. _Did you follow the step where you check using a django shell that your channel layer can establish a connection and communicate with your redis server?_

Comment: it's not clear where in the tutorial you are. In part 2, there's a first half where you create a consumer and as a result it works in one browser tab. in the second half, you update this to enable communication with multiple users (browser tabs) simultaneously. that's where you have to install redis. and check it.